I can't get python to run in my MacOS 12.5 zsh terminal after deleting and reinstalling
After not using Jupyter, python, or my terminal for a while, I returned to find that my Jupyter notebooks were not executing python code. When trying to begin a program I got a "no kernel available" error, so I went to my terminal and ran "python", but I received another error : "command not found: python". I tried to install python using brew, but it said that python was already installed and up-to date. I deleted the python framework, application, and any other python files on my computer as well as the entire brew Cellar, and ran brew doctor and brew cleanup before installing once more. Even after this installation, I'm unable to run "python" in the terminal and I am returned a "command not found" error.

There is no python. If you installed via Homebrew, the binary is python3.
